# A good Java Tool to monitor the heap

Tags: java, memory, jvm, windows-server-2008

I have been searching, and see that there is Jstat, VisualJVM, and even Eclipse mat tools, but they all seem to have the JDK needing to be installed.

I have a third party tool used in my .NET application (separate server instance) that has a JRE installed with it. I don't have the JDK or any Java code, but can't seem to find a tool (like windows task manager), to monitor the Java heap.

Any good (and free) suggestions, with details on why its great, would be helpful.

Comment: If that is any help, I think the JDK is only required for the tools themselves, not for the application being monitored (that can stick with JRE). So you could install a JDK in addition that does not mess with your app.

Comment: I know @Thilo is right about jhat and jmap.  They come with the JDK but they don't require the running application to be using the JDK.  I use these tools an a server started by a JRE all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The eG Innovations Java Monitoring tool - http://www.eginnovations.com/web/java-monitoring.htm